# Why does this show that the plane at which the motion of Q take place?

Tags: vectors, 3d, coordinate-systems

I was trying to give a geometrical description of the the motion of Q, and the motion of Q can be described by the equation: $Q=cos(t+\frac{1}{4}\pi)[\frac{3}{2}\vec{i}+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} \vec{k}] +3sin(t+\frac{1}{4}\pi)\vec{j}$.
By calculating |Q|, we know that the distance from the origin is constant; hence, the particle would travel at a circular path.
After proving that, I took a look at the mark scheme for this question, and the mark scheme indicated that:”it is evident that $\sqrt{3}x - z =0$, and so this defines the plane in which the motion of Q takes place”. I can’t understand what $\sqrt{3}x -z =0$ tells us, and why does it relate to the plane of motion, from my point of view, we can see that the equation of motion has variables in x-y-z, so it is obviously moves in x-y-z.

Thank you very much for you guy’s reply.

Comment: Maybe that you have $\frac{{3}\sqrt{3}}{2}\vec k$  in the equation for $Q$ ?

Comment: Sorry, It is my fault, I copied it wrongly, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the equation of motion for $Q$ as:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{3}{2}\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{4})\\
y=3\sin(t+\frac{\pi}{4})\\
z=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{4})\\
\end{cases}
$$

so, multiplying the first equation by $\sqrt{3}$ ad subtracting the third we find  the equation:
$$
\sqrt{3}x-z=0
$$
This is the equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the fact that the coordinates of $Q$ satisfies this equation  means that the   $Q$ is a point on the plane that has this equation.

Comment: I still don’t quite understand why does the fact that Q satisfies the equation would mean that it is in the plane, why is that so special about that equation. Could u explain for me? Thank you very much sir